# MVC listener in View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I make an ajax request (every interval) from a view to get a response from a controller and update view element accordingly. Is there a way to FLIP it other way around? That is to have the listener on the View and controller would fire an event to update the view?. any examples greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: both of these solutions below will work for what i need to do..so thank you!. However since Adam was first with the answer I'll mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, see SignalR
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR
This is a pretty cool project that allows the server side pushes.

You could also investigate WebSockets, which SignalR didn't use as it was prior to WS, however I think its being rewritten (if not already) to use WebSockets as they are now standard.

Answer (score 0):

Check out XSockets.NET.

You can easily push data from a controller to your view. It uses websockets and supports .NET 4. I can provide you with examples if you need, but there are a few witten on git [enter link description here](https://github.com/codeplanner)

If you need more examples I can add one on git tomorrow.

Regards
Uffe